# Entity Framework Core: Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I use Entity Framework Core in a UWP Project. When I start the application it creates the database. and can basicly access it. But when I execute my tests who in a .net 4.6.1 Class Library project I get this error message:

Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found

I have references this libraries:

```
"Microsoft.Data.SQLite": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.0",
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I just used a .net core project as a unit test project.

Comment: A .NET Core web project?

Comment: No just a plain .net core library project